# horizontal scrolling divs, first div fixed

Tags: html, css, scroll, z-index, koken

I'm designing a portfolio website for a friend, using the KOKEN CMS. The supplied theme is nice but needs some changes. It places all portfolio pictures in a scrollable horizontal band of divs, preceded by a div with intro text. However the theme doesn't allow to have the intro text stay in place, and the following divs scrolling. 
Please take a look at http://www.shakkei.com/klanten/hansmaes/projecten/m-r-houthalen/

So the text block
"TWEE APPARTEMENTEN
aard: nieuwbouw
plaats: Houthalen
ontwerp: 2005
realisatie: 2015"
needs to stay fixed, the pictures should scroll.

Can i have some advice on how to alter the CSS (z-index?,...) to manage this? 
Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can take the div called "wrap" and add "positio:fix" to it and play around to get it the right top and left values; also you need to choose the highest z-index in order to overlap everything. i tried it on google chrome inspect element and these values seems to be fine "position:fixed;top:100px;left:0px;z-index:9999999999"

Comment: You are welcome @Tim Willems, can you please mark the question as the right one:) thank you

Answer (score 0):

**Used to this css**

```
    #lane.cell > .wrap{
    position: fixed;
      top: 102px;
      z-index: 2;
      left: 0;
width: 135px;
    }
```